# Intellij IDEA - how to add support for proper interpretation of YAML document that contains Python and Bash code?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

How can I make Intellij IDEA support proper recognition of file contents, where I have a YAML file with Python and Bash blocks inside? The goal is that the IDE would understand where Python/Bash code should be and under which conditions.

Do I need to write a plugin, or can I use some existing one, define some YAML/JSON schema?

Thank you!

Example code:

```
version: org.riotkit.rkd/0.3
imports:
    - rkd.standardlib.docker
    - rkt_ciutils.boatci
    - rkt_ciutils.docker

env_files:
    - env/build-settings.env

environment:
    ENV_NAME: "taiga"
    COMPOSE_CMD: 'docker-compose -p ${ENV_NAME}'
    SUDO: "sudo -E"

tasks:
    :build-all-versions:
        description: Build all versions of Taiga
        arguments:
            "--commit-msg":
                required: True
        steps: |
            rkd :boat-ci:process --commit-message="${ARG_COMMIT_MSG}"
    :build:snapshot:
        description: Build a single version of Taiga image
        arguments:
            "--backend-version":
                required: True
            "--frontend-version":
                required: True
        steps: >
            rkd :boat-ci:specific-release \
            --app-version="${ARG_BACKEND_VERSION}" \
            --docker-build-opts="--build-arg FRONTEND_VERSION=${ARG_FRONTEND_VERSION}" \
            --docker-version="${ARG_BACKEND_VERSION}-SNAPSHOT" \
            --no-push
    :generate-readme:
        description: Before commiting, please regenerate the README.md from template
        steps: rkd :docker:generate-readme -f ./Dockerfile -rt ./README.md.j2 --target-path ./README.md

    :prepare-env:
        description: Make sure the .env is there
        steps: test -f .env || cp .env.dist .env

    :start:
        description: Start the environment
        env_files:
            - .env
        steps: set -x; VERSION="${VERSION}" ${SUDO} ${COMPOSE_CMD} up -d

    :delete_environment:
        description: Delete all data, including postgres data and uploads (DANGEROUS)
        env_files:
            - .env
        steps:
            - ${SUDO} docker volume rm ${ENV_NAME}_postgres || true
            - ${SUDO} docker volume rm ${ENV_NAME}_media || true
            - ${SUDO} ${COMPOSE_CMD} rm -f

    :clear:
        description: Remove all volumes and containers (DANGEROUS)
        env_files:
            - .env
        steps:
            - set -x; VERSION=${VERSION} ${SUDO} ${COMPOSE_CMD} down -v
            - set -x; VERSION=${VERSION} ${SUDO} ${COMPOSE_CMD} rm -s -f -v

    :shell:
        description: Get into the container's shell
        steps: |
            #!python
            import subprocess
            subprocess.call("set -x; eval \"${SUDO} ${COMPOSE_CMD} exec taiga bash\"", shell=True, env=os.environ)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [language injections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) (from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> intention actions menu) to inject Shell script and Python into the code fragments:

[image]
[image]